# Storing accessToken in Facebook iOS SDK

Tags: ios, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-ios-sdk, facebook-access-token

I have the [Facebook iOS SDK](https://github.com/facebook/facebook-ios-sdk) set up in my app. However, I have trouble determining when my session is finished. How to check if it's finished, and where (how) to store the access token received by the login?

I need to determine whether I have the access token or not right from the beginning so I know whether to log in again, or go forward in the app.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Are you familiar with NSUserDefaults ?  It is for storing preferences for your app.

They are extremely easy to use, and probably what you are looking for. So it's just something like ..

```
NSUserDefaults *factoids;
NSString *whateverIDstring; // make this a property for convenience  

factoids = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
self.whateverIDstring = [factoids stringForKey:@"storeTheStringHere"];

if ( ( whateverIDstring == Nil ) || ( [whateverIDstring isEqualToString:@""] ) )
    // it does not yet exist, so try to make a new one...
else
    // we already made one last time the program ran

// when you make a new one, save it in the prefs file like this...   
[factoids setObject:yourNewString forKey:@"storeTheStringHere"];
[factoids synchronize];
```

Hope it helps!

***ONE*** get the preferences in to 'factoids' as in the example above

***TWO*** decide on a name for your preference. 'storeTheStringHere' in the example.

***THREE*** get your string 'whateverIDstring' in the example using stringForKey:

***FOUR*** check if it is either nil or blank. if so, start fresh.

***FIVE*** once you get the value, save it as shown!

Hope it helps!

Comment: Also the DemoApp that comes with Facebook iOS SDK does exactly that.

Comment: I don't see it in the demo app.

Comment: This does help a lot, however I'm not quite sure how to go about this.  I'm getting pretty confused when you make the variable padIDString and padFactoids.  I'm sure about using NSUserDefaults, though.

Comment: @JohnJ you're right actually, it is twitter that users NSUserDefaults to save you're logged in state. I'll have a look and report back if I find something that might help you.

Comment: Thanks @Rog and @Joe Blow.  Hopefully I can get on the right track now.

Comment: I've stored the access token exactly how you are saying, but I don't know what to do with it to get the facebook-ios-sdk to accept the user without login.